# How do I make my code remove what is after the .png in an image source?

Tags: png, sharepoint-2013

this is the script I am using, I want my script to remove the part after the .png which is 'RenditionID=1'
for example my image link is : `myimage.png?RenditionId=1`

the script I am using:

```
var src = this.src;

var newsrc = src.substring(0, src.indexOf("?RenditionID=1"));

var x = window.open( newsrc+".png","","location=0, status=1, toolbar=0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
var src = this.src;
var newsrc = src.split("?")[0]
```